# Hiding/Showing images jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

Alright.
What I want to do is create a few buttons up top, which will hide/show elements.

If the user presses "350x150" it will hide all the images except for the "350x150" images.

> 1). User presses "350x150" 
> 2). All images hide except for the
>   two "350x150"

I tried using some jQuery to hide images but it did not work.
 How would I do this?

[image: What I want it to look like]
The images are done like this:

```
                <div class="Collage">
                    <img class="boom" src="http://placehold.it/1000x150">
                    <img class="ei" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
                    <img class="boom" src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
                    <img class="ei" src="http://placehold.it/200x350">
                    <img class="350x150" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
                    <img class="350x150" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
                    <img class="boom" src="http://placehold.it/500x150">
                    <img class="ei" src="http://placehold.it/50x200">
                    <img class="boom" src="http://placehold.it/350x200">
                    <img class="ei" src="http://placehold.it/600x200">
                </div>
```

Comment: You need to have a attribute which will relate images with the buttons you are clicking..

Comment: Show us your jQuery.

Comment: you should really show what you have already tried to resolve your own problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add to your filter btns class let's say "filter-btn" and then their id's could be the same as the class you want to show, for example id="350x150" or id="boom" or id="ei"... I think you get the point :)

```
$(".filter-btn").click(function(){
var filterVal = "." + $(this).attr("id");
  $(".Collage img").show();
  $(".Collage img").not(filterVal).hide();
});
```

Or you can first hide all and then show those that you need:

```
$(".filter-btn").click(function(){
var filterVal = "." + $(this).attr("id");
  $(".Collage img").hide();
  $(".Collage img").filter(filterVal).show();
});
```

**EDIT** or better cache your elements:

```
var $collageImages = $(".Collage").find("img"); // cache your elements!
$("#filter350x150").click(function(){
  $collageImages.hide();  // Hide all
  $(".350x150").show();   // Show desired ones
});
// other buttons here...
```

or with a more versatile code:

```
var $collageImages = $(".Collage").find("img"); // cache your elements!
$("[id^=filter]").click(function(){  // any button which ID starts with "filter"
  var class = this.id.split("filter")[1]; // get the filterXYZ suffix
  $collageImages.hide();                  // Hide all
  $collageImages.is("."+ class ).show()   // Show desired ones
});
```

Comment: If there are other filter buttons, you'd better also include `$("img.350x150").show()` to ensure that the .350x150 images are visible.

Comment: How about hiding only those which does not match the filter. Makes sense ?

Comment: @ZoranP. have oyu tested your second example? I don't think it'll work. what are you filtering there?

Comment: `<div class="Collage">
                        <script>
                            var $collageImages = $(".Collage").find("img");
                        </script>`
Gives me this, I think I'm doing something terribly wrong.
http://i.imgur.com/ZNiDE6g.png

Comment: I am using CollagePlus to generate a collage, perhaps it does not allow any changes after it has generated the collage? Hence the plain text instead of the script working?

Comment: thanks Roko. 
@Thais if you need collage and also filtering, maybe your best bet would be to use a library like Isotope. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html

Comment: Oh my! Thank you tons, exactly what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use class name, which starts not with a number. I had a lot of troubles in case of it.
For example `<img class="res350x150" src="" />`